# Using localPosition to create a property based tracking system

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, objects

So I have been using this code to broadcast coordinates so other objects can read the properties. The problem is that when I an using a vector I cannot tell if it is in the negatives or positives. Plus when I'm using a parented set, it goes off the median object location.

```
import mathutils
import bge

owner = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
positionToCheck = owner.worldPosition
positionToCompareTo = mathutils.Vector([0,0,0])
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

own["position.x"] = float(abs(owner.worldPosition.x))
own["position.y"] = float(abs(owner.worldPosition.y))
```

The position.x and y are properties on the given object that I make other objects read for various reasons. I'd like another way to accomplish this without a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
 So this is the code I ended up using. But then I realized I can just check the worldPosition.x and y directly. So this was kind of a dumb question sorry